# Framework to develop Google Chrome Extension "Session Buddy"

Tags: google-chrome, frameworks

I'd love to develop Google Chrome Extension. But currently I don't know any framework to work with. I found the "Session Buddy" is one of very well structured extensions. I think it must be developed by specific framework (because it's very well structured, and encoded).

Anyone know what framework does the author of Session Buddy use to develop this extension? Here is the url: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/edacconmaakjimmfgnblocblbcdcpbko?hl=en-US

Moreover what other frameworks do you use to create chrome extension? Does it support unit test?

Thanks for your answers,

[nTuan16](http://blog.veev.vn)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The current version of Session Buddy (v3.0.9) is coded in pure JavaScript, with the exception that it uses MooTools for internationalization of dates and ordinals (I'm currently exploring alternatives to that though, so this may be replaced in favor of a different library in a future release). The code obfuscation is achieved through a simple js parser I built using C#.

-Hans (Session Buddy developer)

Addendum: I should add (because you mention the code structure) that I pass the code through Google's Closure Compiler with a compilation level of WHITESPACE_ONLY.

Comment: Hi Hans, I admire you a lot. I have not enough reputation point to vote up your answer, so I leave you a comment instead. Thanks for your great chrome extension, and also for your rapid answer. It's very useful for me.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate the compliment. I wish I could have provided more information with respect to different frameworks/libraries that might facilitate your work, but I don't have enough experience with any of them to recommend one with any sense of authority. jQuery seems to be the prevailing general-purpose js library, so I'd start there if you haven't already. I will say this: while using something like jQuery to build Session Buddy would have surely expedited the effort, I feel like I learned a lot about js that I would have missed out on had I done so.